# evaluate_generator in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, evaluate

I'm training a Convolutional Autoencoder model. I've taken batch size 100 for the test set, have run `model.evaluate_generator` on the test set and `evaluate_generator` has given a value. However, when I'm changing the batch size of the test set from 100 to 60 or to 200, `evaluate_generator` is giving me a different value.

Is it obvious or am I making any mistake somewhere?

And for clarification - the loss function that I'll define while compiling my model, that function will be used by `evaluate_generator` - right? So, like in my case, I'm using mean square error as the loss-function while compiling; hence `evaluate_generator` will also calculate the mse on test set.

Comment: What do you mean by "is giving me different value"? What metric is this "value" representing?

Comment: For batch_size 100, the value was 0.0091856; batch_size 60, 0.0091029 and batch_size 200, 0.0093822 - these different values are coming.

Comment: Ok. So either your test data is not the same on multiple batch sizes or model accuracy is being changed along the way. Are you having a consistent result when testing on the same batch sizes multiple times?

Comment: No, I'm not having the same result while testing on the same batch sizes multiple times. But my test data is same.

Comment: What's the size of your test set in total? There is a possibility that test set size is not a multiplicity of batch size which results in a different mean for the last batch